# Flutter run command only works with sudo

Tags: android, flutter

i installed flutter on my macbook following the instructions from the official [flutter website](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos) and it consequently fails with error :``Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty, how do i run without using sudo?

```
enter code hereException in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1567)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1375)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1469)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1274)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1237)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:727)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

[Complete error on machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDzWK.png)

Comment: Please add the error as a text inside the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it last,the issue was with permissions had to change owner of both the flutter and project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Browse to the official Gradle Distributions webpage and check what is the latest version of gradle all.zip file, for example (at the time of writing) gradle-6.7-all.zip and copy the address

Go to your Flutter project dropdown,

drop down android>gradle>wrapper

Select gradle-wrapper-properties

Paste the URL you copied earlier. For example:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

Comment: * What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Cannot create service of type DependencyLockingHandler using method DefaultDependencyManagementServices$DependencyResolutionScopeServices.createDependencyLockingHandler() as there is a problem with parameter #2 of type ConfigurationContainerInternal.
   > Cannot create service of type ConfigurationContainerInternal using method DefaultDependencyManagementServices$DependencyResolutionScopeServices.createConfigurationContainer() as there is a ....

Comment: thats the error i got now